# How can I return one row rather than two?

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
--Invoice summary by class
SELECT HHICUSN AS "Account", FFDCNMB AS "Name", HHICLSN AS "Class", FFBSDSC AS "Description",
       --SUM(HHIQYSA),
       CASE HHIBCCD WHEN 'Y' THEN SUM(HHIQYSA) ELSE 0 END AS "Piece",
       CASE HHIBCCD WHEN 'Y' THEN 0 ELSE SUM(HHIQYSA) END AS "Case",
       SUM(HHIEXSN) AS "Extended"

FROM S2151BDW.PWRDTA.HHIORDDP
JOIN S2151BDW.PWRDTA.HHHORDHP ON HHHINVN = HHIINVN AND HHHCMPN = HHICMPN
JOIN S2151BDW.PWRDTA.FFDCSTBP ON FFDCUSN = HHHCUSN AND FFDCMPN = HHICMPN
JOIN S2151BDW.PWRDTA.FFBCLSAP ON FFBCLSN = HHICLSN AND FFBCMPN = HHICMPN

WHERE HHICMPN = '  1' AND
      
    --**********************************************
      HHICUSN = '    960143' AND --10 characters
      HHIDTES BETWEEN '20200101' AND '20201016'
    --**********************************************

GROUP BY HHICUSN, FFDCNMB, HHICLSN, FFBSDSC, HHIBCCD
ORDER BY HHICLSN
```

It returns this:
[image]

I want lines 2 and 3 on one line, I need one line per class, how can I do this? I am somewhat new to SQL.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: The more columns in your `group by` the more potential rows in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are grouping by `HHIBCCD`, the following should work:

```
SELECT HHICUSN AS "Account", FFDCNMB AS "Name", HHICLSN AS "Class", FFBSDSC AS "Description",
       --SUM(HHIQYSA),
       SUM(CASE WHEN HHIBCCD = 'Y' THEN HHIQYSA ELSE 0 END) AS "Piece",
       SUM(CASE WHEN HHIBCCD = 'Y' THEN 0 ELSE HHIQYSA END) AS "Case",
       SUM(HHIEXSN) AS "Extended"

FROM S2151BDW.PWRDTA.HHIORDDP
JOIN S2151BDW.PWRDTA.HHHORDHP ON HHHINVN = HHIINVN AND HHHCMPN = HHICMPN
JOIN S2151BDW.PWRDTA.FFDCSTBP ON FFDCUSN = HHHCUSN AND FFDCMPN = HHICMPN
JOIN S2151BDW.PWRDTA.FFBCLSAP ON FFBCLSN = HHICLSN AND FFBCMPN = HHICMPN

WHERE HHICMPN = '  1' AND
      
    --**********************************************
      HHICUSN = '    960143' AND --10 characters
      HHIDTES BETWEEN '20200101' AND '20201016'
    --**********************************************

GROUP BY HHICUSN, FFDCNMB, HHICLSN, FFBSDSC
ORDER BY HHICLSN
```

Comment: When I try that I get this error: Column HHIBCCD or expression in SELECT list not valid.. SQLCODE=-122, SQLSTATE=42803, DRIVER=3.69.56

Comment: Changed the CASE WHEN part, could you try again. What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should exclude the fields that differ from the group by clause, you can use sum, avg or some calcuations to find those fields